# Creating MapView from decoded coordinates - swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, view, mapkit

I am setting up a MapView with custom coordinates. Here is my code thus far

```
var coordModel: AirportModel?

struct MapView: View {
    
    
    
    @Binding private var lat: Double
    @Binding private var lon: Double

    private let initialLatitudinalMetres: Double = coordModel?.airportLat ?? 0
    private let initialLongitudinalMetres: Double = coordModel?.airportLong ?? 0

    @State private var span: MKCoordinateSpan?

    init(lat: Binding<Double>, lon: Binding<Double>) {
        _lat = lat
        _lon = lon
    }

    private var region: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
        Binding {
            let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

            if let span = span {
                return MKCoordinateRegion(center: centre, span: span)
            } else {
                return MKCoordinateRegion(center: centre, latitudinalMeters: initialLatitudinalMetres, longitudinalMeters: initialLongitudinalMetres)
            }
        } set: { region in
            lat = region.center.latitude
            lon = region.center.longitude
            span = region.span
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: region)
    }
}
```

In the AirportModel, there is a piece of data decoded in Double form called "latitude" and "longitude." I am simply trying to pass these data into the view after they are decoded. Here is my view body:

```
var body: some View {
    
        ScrollView{
            MapView(lat: <#Binding<Double>#>, lon: <#Binding<Double>#>)
                .frame(height: 250)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
}
```

I have tried putting coordModel?.latitude and coordModel?.longitude in for lat and lon, as well as setting variables above the call. I'm not quite sure where to go now.

Note: I am decoding a bunch of JSON data and every user query results in a different lat/lon pull (over 10000 potential responses). Thanks again!

Comment: Does your airport model contain shapes like buildings and shops or only points? If you want to display shapes on a map, forget SwiftUI. SwiftUI Maps has no overlays. Go back to good old MKMapKit if you want overlays.

Comment: It’s not supposed to show anything except a last and long coordinate group

Comment: What you are searching for are Annotations. This is a simple intro how to show annotations: https://medium.com/better-programming/an-introduction-to-map-in-swiftui-ec3a310fcbbd

Comment: That's a great article, thank you. However, I still need to figure out how to pass the decoded lat and long from the api call and put them in dynamically on the single view that displays the weather report for that airport - not something I can hard code because of the sheer number of possible airports.

Comment: Not answering your questions: weather data can come on form of map tiles (not what you are doing now) And SwiftUI Maps can't do this, lacking TileOverlays and overlays at all. If there is at least a small chance that you need this, use the old `MKMapKit`.

Comment: I’m sorry for not being clear. This is an app primarily for displaying aviation weather reports and airport information. I am making multiple API calls and in one of those calls there is available latitude and longitude of the station. Those coordinates are what I am trying to display.

Comment: Do you want to change the center of your map from your data or do you want to display one station on the map as an annotation or both?

Comment: Change center based on search

Comment: then my answer is exactly what you need. It changes the center based on a timer, you replace that by a search. As soon as you update the model variable, the view shows the new center/region. Run my example and you see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use a model that is an `ObservableObject`:

```
import Combine
import MapKit

class MapModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.687330584, longitude: 9.219832454),
        latitudinalMeters: 1000000,
        longitudinalMeters: 1000000
    ) {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - test code change center evey 10 seconds
    
    init() {
        
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.testIndex += 1
            self.testIndex %= self.testCoordinates.count
            let newCenter = self.testCoordinates[self.testIndex]
            let oldSpan = self.region.span
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newCenter, span: oldSpan)
            }
        }
    }
    
    let testCoordinates = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.687330584, longitude: 9.219832454), // STR
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.297445, longitude: 2.0832941),  // BCN
    ]
    var testIndex: Int = 0
    
    var timer: Timer? = nil
    
    
}
```

then create a View that observes your model

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var mapModel = MapModel()

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $mapModel.region)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

For test reasons I used a timer that simulates updated data from a server.

If you need Annotations, add them to the model and don't forget `self.objectWillChange.send()` if you change them.

Comment: How could I modify that code to update when a new query is entered and perform the same call but with a different search query each time? See https://avwx.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/station/get-station-information for the API I am trying to get the lat/long from.

Comment: just set MapModel.region and the map updates automatically